# La aplicación no responde al evento setOnItemClickListener del listview

Tags: android

El evento setOnItemClickListener, no funciona, es decir ejecuta la pantalla del listado pero no regresa al activity que lo invocó.
Este es mi código:

```
public class SeleccionClienteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout lyCliente;
private ListView listaCliente;
private List<Cliente> clientes;
private String fecha2;
Cliente cliente= new Cliente();
String [] cli={String.valueOf(cliente.getCodigo()), cliente.getNombre()};
private TextView txtfecha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccion_cliente);

    txtfecha = findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
    lyCliente = findViewById(R.id.lyCliente);

    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fecha2 = formato.format(calendar.getTime());
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    txtfecha.setText(fecha2);

    listaCliente = findViewById(R.id.lvClienteList);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    listaCliente.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(SeleccionClienteActivity.this, RegistroPedidoActivity.class);
            Cliente cliente= new Cliente();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("NOMBRE", cliente.getNombre());

            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    ClienteService clienteService = APICliente.getClient().create(ClienteService.class);

    Call call = clienteService.findAll();
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            clientes = (List<Cliente>) response.body();
            listaCliente.setAdapter(new ClienteListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), clientes));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falló", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: Que mensaje se muestra en el LogCat, Cuando das clic, deseas abrir RegistroPedidoActivity y regresar SeleccionClienteActivity???. Desde luego que podemos ayudarte no olvides leer [ask] y realizar el [tour].